# Facebook Graph API doesn't return profile image for one page

Tags: url, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

*Apologies, I can only include 2 URLs as a new user so I have had to econonomize.*

I am having a problem where the user object in Facebook's Graph API is not returning a profile image correctly. I can only find one case of this problem. For all other uses I have tested it appears to be working correctly. The profile image doesn't seem to have any privacy settings, since I'm able to view it normally from the profile page.

I am using Facebook's Graph API to load the profile image for a user/page by putting this URL into an IMG tag:

> https://graph.facebook.com/[profile-id]/picture?type=square

This has worked in all cases I found during testing, including pages and users. For one of our users deploying the app on a page, however, the URL is loading the question mark image, as though there is no profile image for the page. Their page clearly has a profile image, as you can see here:

> http://www.facebook.com/EgansRestaurantPub

But if you click through to the Egan's Calendar tab, you'll see the question mark image. The image URL is the following, which returns the question mark:

> https://graph.facebook.com/400488613342471/picture?type=square

I've checked the ID using the following link format, to ensure it's the right ID for the page:

> http://www.facebook.com/pages/[anything]/400488613342471

My first theory was that there were privacy settings on the profile image, but my personal account (as a non-fan of the page) is able to view the profile image. My only other idea is that perhaps it is because the page uses a short URL (EgansRestaurantPub) that doesn't include the page ID. For similar pages, I found using the following worked:

> [graphurl]/cocacola/picture
>
> [graphurl]/BMW/picture

But when using the same method for my client's page, it still returns a question mark.

Does anyone know why this is not returning the profile image for this page? This is the only page where I have found this problem.

I am using the PHP SDK and a bit of the JS SDK. I would prefer to avoid making another call to the API that would delay loading the page. That's why I liked being able to throw the URL straight into the IMG tag. But I will make another call if there is no other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there is some kind of restriction as mentioned in the [`user`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) document (picture field):

> `access_token` required for pages with whitelisting/targeting
>   restrictions, otherwise no `access_token` required

You just need to supply a user `access_token` for this to work:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/400488613342471/picture?type=square&access_token=XXX
```

To test this, you can directly get an access_token from the [Access Token Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/).

Comment: Yes. It looks like the page's owner has set an age and/or country restriction on this page, perhaps by marking it "alcohol-related". You can only access a page's content with a user access token that meets the criteria. I'd message the owner and ask them to remove this restriction.

Comment: Thanks to both for your help. I was able to reproduce this problem on a test page by setting the Age Restrictions to "alchol-related". I haven't yet got the access_token working properly, but I will report back success/failure with that.

Comment: BaseFacebook->getAccessToken() in the PHP SDK worked without complications. I'm not sure what would happen if the access token was for a user who did not meet the age restrictions, but I guess they shouldn't be able to view the page anyway. Thanks again.

Comment: Why do you need a special request for a picture? FB has to return a picture for `/me` request because it is `public_profile` by default https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions